# Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request) on registring with facebook API on my website

Tags: laravel, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, laravel-5.6

I have problem on integrating the facebook login/signup api,In my laravel project when I run php artisan serve, and after that when I register through facebook,My Chrome Browser blocks it with a message "localhost unexpectedly closed the connection." And at Command line I got this message "Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)". I cant figure out whats the problem